# Why 'delete' will not work with local variables in javascript ?

Tags: javascript

Here is the code

```
(function(x){
   delete x;
   return x;
})(1);
```

Even after deleted variable x , it will still work and return value 1.

Is delete only work for object property and global variables?

Comment: Yes right it wont work with Variable.

Comment: @FahadNisar got it, thank you

Comment: Note that implicit global variables (i.e. those created by assignment without the use of *var*) **can** be deleted, but those created using *var* **can't**. It's one of the major differences between using *var* and not (the other being when the variable is created).

Comment: Great point from @RobG -- my hunch is that this is related to the fact that, in the browser, global variables actually exist as properties on the `window` object.  As such, they match the description of being properties on an object and are subject to deletion in that manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `delete` operator is *only* to be used for the [deletion of properties on an object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete).  It cannot be leveraged to delete a variable-- nor are there generally use cases in JavaScript where such a thing is necessary.  You can always set the variable to `null` or `undefined` as a substitute.